# RSA keyblock wrapper: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error

Tags: java, security, encryption

In a larger application doing other things - I need to encrypt and decrypt a file. So I have been looking around and have implemented these two core functions that basically use RSA keys to wrap a random AES key that encrypts a file. The symmetric key and iv are written to the start of the file.

I'm getting an exception ("javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error") in the decrypt function portion of below. On the unpackKeyandIV line -- the doFinal. Specifically this line is the Exception point:
Object[] keyIv = unpackKeyAndIV(xCipher.doFinal(keyBlock));

I've checked and remade the RSA key pairs. I've also checked the save/load of the keyBlock.

My gut is the problem has something to do with how I write/read the keyBlock --- or encoding perhaps?

One goal is to keep the RSA/AES instance as generic as possible so as not to need Bouncy Castle or extra Java security unlimited strength extensions.

Any thoughts on where I might be going wrong.

Thanks in advance.
[Final update: This code below is working. Error was passing in a corrupted privKey]

```
// RSA_INSTANCE = "RSA";
// ASSYM_CRYPTO_STR = 1024;
// SYM_CRYPTO_STR = 128;
// SYM_CRYPTO = "AES";
// AES_INSTANCE = "AES/CTR/NoPadding";
//
// File in = plain input file
// File out = encrypted output file
// Key pubKey = public Key (that wraps a random AES key)
public static void encryptFile(File in, File out, Key pubKey) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream fin;
    FileOutputStream fout;
    int nread = 0; 
    byte[] inbuf = new byte[1024];
    fout = new FileOutputStream(out);
    fin = new FileInputStream(in);

    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    // symmetric wrapping
    Key sKey = createKeyForAES(Config.SYM_CRYPTO_STR, random);
    IvParameterSpec sIvSpec = createCtrIvForAES(0, random);

    // encrypt symmetric key with RSA/pub key
    Cipher xCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Config.RSA_INSTANCE);
    xCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey, random);
    byte[] keyBlock = xCipher.doFinal(packKeyAndIv(sKey, sIvSpec));

    fout.write(keyBlock);

    // encrypt data with symmetric key
    Cipher sCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Config.AES_INSTANCE);
    sCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sKey, sIvSpec);

    // Now read our file and encrypt it.
    while((nread = fin.read(inbuf)) > 0) {
        fout.write(sCipher.update(inbuf, 0, nread)); // cannot be null, by construction
    }
    // NB doFinal() cannot return null, but can return a zero-length array, which is benign below.
    fout.write(sCipher.doFinal());

    fout.flush();
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
}


// Decrypt File
public static void decryptFile(File in, File out, Key privKey) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream fin;
    FileOutputStream fout;
    int nread = 0; 
    byte[] inbuf = new byte[1024];
    fout = new FileOutputStream(out);
    fin = new FileInputStream(in);

    byte[] keyBlock = new byte[128];
    nread = fin.read(keyBlock);

    Cipher xCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Config.RSA_INSTANCE);
    Cipher sCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Config.AES_INSTANCE);   

    // symmetric key/iv unwrapping step
    xCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey);
    Object[] keyIv = unpackKeyAndIV(xCipher.doFinal(keyBlock));

    // decryption step
    sCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, (Key)keyIv[0], (IvParameterSpec)keyIv[1]);

    while((nread = fin.read(inbuf)) >0) {
        fout.write(sCipher.update(inbuf,0,nread));
    }
    fout.write(sCipher.doFinal());

    fout.flush();
    fin.close();
    fout.close();

}

public static byte[] packKeyAndIv(Key key, IvParameterSpec ivSpec) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bOut.write(ivSpec.getIV());
    bOut.write(key.getEncoded());
    return bOut.toByteArray();
}

public static Object[] unpackKeyAndIV(byte[] data) {
    byte[] keyD = new byte[16];
    byte[] iv = new byte[data.length - 16];

    return new Object[] {
        new SecretKeySpec(data, 16, data.length - 16, "AES"),
        new IvParameterSpec(data, 0, 16)
    };
}
```

Comment: 1) `byte[] keyBlock = new byte[128];` - are you sure that the stored key is 128 bytes? On writing, you should store the length and then the byte array.
2) `nread = fin.read(keyBlock);` - this is not guaranteed to read the `keyBlock` fully.

Comment: a System.out.println(keyBlock.length) equals 128 after fout.write in the encrypt function. Same result on decrypt after the fin.read. Regarding suggestion to also store the length - I'll add that now to the function as well.

Comment: The point is that an AES key is not 128 *bytes*, it is 128, 192, or 256 *bits*. Also, your `packKeyAndIV` method is critical since you are doing your own padding. An error there can be hard to detect and might result in the exception you observe.

Comment: @GregS : correct. In this case due to constuction - my sKey is 128 bits (or 16 bytes). The problem with above is it is bombing out in the keyBlock. The keyBlock is a combination of the symmetric key + IV = 128 bytes. I modified the code to write the size of the keyblock first (confirmed 128 bytes) and then read the size (in this case 128 bytes) and then read the keyblock. Still bombs with a javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error. Any more thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect the critical method is `packKeyAndIV` which you haven't shown. However, I'll attempt to create some simple versions of these and see what if any errors I get.

Comment: will add to code above the pack/unpack. Exception is in the doFinal part of the unpack.

Comment: I'm starting to think above code is fine and the error is in the pubKey/privKey..

Comment: ugggh - I'm embarrassed. sorry. I've wasted your time. My private key was corrupted 5 steps before this and wasn't coming through properly. Rookie error. Above code is working fine now that the private key being passed in correctly. I'll accept that as your answer if you want to post one. Cheers.

Comment: No need, glad you fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per edits and comments. Error was a corrupted privKey being passed into the decrypt function. Above code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following under your constructor -

Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());